# Are passwords for system users/roles stored in encrypted form in YugabyteDB YSQL and YCQL?

Tags: sql, database, cql, distributed-database, yugabytedb

When we create users/roles (see examples below) how are the passwords stored persistently? Are these stored in some encrypted form, and not as plain text?

```
# YSQL
CREATE USER tester WITH PASSWORD 'test_password';
```

or,

```
# YCQL
CREATE ROLE IF NOT EXISTS john WITH PASSWORD = 'test_password' AND LOGIN = true
```

Answer (score 2):

For both APIs they are stored in an encrypted form.